# how to change view constraint top margin programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using constraint layout and I have a view like this

```
<View
           android:id="@+id/view_separator_line"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="1dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
           android:background="@color/grey_dark_low"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_gear_setting_user_information"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_following_profile_picture"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_following_profile_picture" />
```

as you can see from the xml above, top of this view is constrained to the bottom of another view, and the layout margin top is 32dp, I want to change it programmatically to be 24dp, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

try this below code

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
     newLayoutParams.topMargin = 0;
     newLayoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
     newLayoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
     toolbar.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams););
```